# When resizing screen to 768px the navigation change style

Tags: javascript, css

I am building mobile navigation. When the screen size is smaller then 768px it stays in the black header. 
As long as the site is wide 768 the navbar appear in row outside the black header.
I want this nav to always stay in the black header and not change style when screen is larger then 768px. How do I do this?

I played around with the media quires of 768, but nothing seems to work..

Comment: My js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Tokyo/mrsbo606/

Comment: use `@media` CSS , look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Please look at my code, I have already have @mediaquires used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   //Put some css here that will make nav to stay in the black header
}
```

Comment: hi the problem is that, I already have the mediaquires on my codes. When I tried to  modify the mediaquires, nothing work..

Comment: I think your media query is been over writing. Use !important to your css. Put your media query at end line of css.